# Как в xcode swift 3 сделать микс двух аудио-файлов?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Всем привет, пишу приложение. Два mp3 аудио дорожки нужно смиксовать параллельно программно чтобы они играли одновременно. Кто знает как это сделать это в xcode 3? Подскажите как написать код? Со звуком программно начал совсем недавно работать, не могу разобраться(

Comment: Что значит "нужно чтобы они играли одновременно и в определенное время в конечном мп3 файле"?

Comment: Думаю, что вопрос не по адресу. Сведением дорожек должна заниматься спец программа. Если же хотите написать свою - перефразируйте вопрос

Comment: "Кто знает как это сделать подскажите как написать код?" swift 3

Comment: справился сам, спасибо за внимание...)